# Router getting cut off

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

When my roommate tries to connect to the wifi from his room, the router cut off. I think the problem is only when a device is in his room. We are having no issues while using the internet in the hall or in my room. He used to connect to wifi from his room before. What could be the reason for this? 
The router is Smart RG SR360n by [our internet service provider](https://www.acanac.com/) Acanac. The connection is DSL. 
I would like to get some suggestions?

Thanks for reading

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the router cut off"? Does it turn off?

Comment: Yes, It turns off and I have to restart the router.